# pip install extern work for python 3 but not python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install a package that requires `extern`. However, it depends on which Python I use.

For Python 3:

```
$ ~ sudo pip3 install extern
Collecting extern
  Downloading extern-0.2.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: extern
  Running setup.py install for extern ... done
Successfully installed extern-0.2.1
```

But, Python 2 hates it:

```
$ ~ sudo pip2 install extern
Collecting extern
  Downloading extern-0.2.1.tar.gz
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 377, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named extern
```

Any reasons why? And how would I fix it so my Python 2 could work?

Comment: Are you able to `pip install` any other mods in python2? Or is it specific to this package?

Comment: just this package. I can pretty much do `pip install` to most of them. 'Most' since I have yet encountered one I couldn't.

Comment: Try this out: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1064

Comment: do you have setuptools installed?